# передать @string в activity

Tags: java, android

В папке res/values есть файл string.xml в нем есть строка:
`<string name="linkads">"https:google.com/"</string>`
есть еще файл string.xml на другом языке.
Есть mainactivity в котором есть:

```
List<String> links = new ArrayList(){
 {
    add(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.linkads));
 }
 };
```

У меня почему-то происходит вылет когда я вызываю этот List

ошибка:
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

Comment: Раскройте подробнее что именно вы хотите сделать. Без этого сложно конкретно ответить, т.к. не ясно про что именно рассказывать - что такое ресурсы, как передавать данные меж актвити или как получить программно строку из ресурсов.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо Вам за уточнение. Я исправил

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я изменил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Это уже новый вопрос, лучше его отдельно задавать, а не полностью менять уже имеющийся. Но вот вам ответ: `List<String> links = new ArrayList(){{(add(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.linkads));}};`

Comment: Все равно вылет.
В вопросе я добавил код, как я его записал.
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

Comment: Если вы это прямо при объявлении переменной на уровне класса вызываете, то контекста там ещё нет. Перенесите объявление или инициализацию или наполнение данными в `onCreate()` например

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо! Это помогло, но я не пойму, что я делаю не так, вот новый вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1166353/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7-string-xml-%d0%b2-activity

Comment: Если ответ вам помог - вы его можете пометить "верным", нажав на галочку слева от тела ответа. За это даже репутацию на сайте получите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае с `Toast`, есть метод, принимающий число, являющееся идентификатором строкового ресурса. В вашем случае, будет выглядеть так:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.fun, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

В случаях, когда методов, принимающих число, являющееся идентификатором строкового ресурса нет и вам надо получить строку из ID ресурса, вы можете сделать так:

```
String string = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.fun);
```

Comment: Юрий, скажите пожалуйста, а если у меня: ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("СЮДА")); тот же метод?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Если вы про получение массива строк из ресурсов, то как то так надо: `context.gerResources().getStingArray(R.array.my_array);`