# Передать список ссылок из string.xml в Activity

Tags: java, android

Всем привет!

В string.xml есть:

```
<string name="linkads">"https://google.com", "https://yandex.ru", "https://bing.com"</string>
```

Есть MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public int index = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            List<String> links =new ArrayList() {
                {
                    add(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.linkads));
                }
            };

            if (index <= links.size()){
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(links.get(index)));
                startActivity(i);
            }else{
                // ссылки кончились
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf("The assignments are over."), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("TAG", "The rewarded ad wasn't loaded yet.");
            }
            index++;

        }});
}

}
```

При нажатии на кнопку открывается только первая ссылка, остальные пропускаются и выводится else{// ссылки кончились...}

Помогите пожалуйста решить данную проблему. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не храните ваши ссылки как массив. Вы храните одну длинную строку, содержащую ссылки.

Вам надо примерно так сделать в ресурсах:

```
<string-array name="stringArray">
    <item>ссылка один, без кавычек</item>
    <item>ссылка два, без кавычек</item>
</string-array>
```

И так в коде:

```
List<String> links = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stringArray)));
```